# Combining nosetests with contracts for Python

Tags: python, design-by-contract, nosetests

I'm using [contracts for Python](http://www.wayforward.net/pycontract/) to specify preconditons/postconditions/invariants. I'm also using doctests for doing unit testing.

I'd like to have all of my doctest unit tests run with contracts enabled, and I'd like to run my tests using [nose](http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose/0.11.1/). Unfortunately, if I run the tests with nose, it does not execute the pre/post/invariant assertions. I put a [setup function](http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose/0.11.1/doc_tests/test_doctest_fixtures/doctest_fixtures.html#module-level-fixtures) in each .py file to make sure that `contract.checkmod` gets called

```
def setup():
    import contract
    contract.checkmod(__name__)
```

I  can confirm that this function is being executed by nose before it runs the tests, but the contracts still don't get executed.

On the other hand, if I run the doctest by calling `doctest.testmod`, the pre/post/inv do get called:

```
def _test():
    import contract
    contract.checkmod(__name__)
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()

if __name__=='__main__':    
    _test()
```

Here's an example of a Python script whose test will succeed if called directly, but failed if called with nose:

```
import os

def setup():
    import contract
    contract.checkmod(__name__)

def delete_file(path):
    """Delete a file. File must be present.

    >>> import minimock
    >>> minimock.mock('os.remove')
    >>> minimock.mock('os.path.exists', returns=True)

    >>> delete_file('/tmp/myfile.txt')
    Called os.path.exists('/tmp/myfile.txt')
    Called os.remove('/tmp/myfile.txt')

    >>> minimock.restore()

    pre: os.path.exists(path)
    """
    os.remove(path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup()
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

When I run the above file standalone, the tests pass:

```
$ python contracttest.py -v
Trying:
    import minimock
Expecting nothing
ok
Trying:
    minimock.mock('os.remove')
Expecting nothing
ok
Trying:
    minimock.mock('os.path.exists', returns=True)
Expecting nothing
ok
Trying:
    delete_file('/tmp/myfile.txt')
Expecting:
    Called os.path.exists('/tmp/myfile.txt')
    Called os.remove('/tmp/myfile.txt')
ok
Trying:
    minimock.restore()
Expecting nothing
ok
2 items had no tests:
    __main__
    __main__.setup
1 items passed all tests:
   5 tests in __main__.delete_file
5 tests in 3 items.
5 passed and 0 failed.
Test passed.
```

Here it is with nose:

```
$ nosetests --with-doctest contracttest.py
F
======================================================================
FAIL: Doctest: contracttest.delete_file
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/doctest.py", line 2131, in runTest
    raise self.failureException(self.format_failure(new.getvalue()))
AssertionError: Failed doctest test for contracttest.delete_file
  File "/Users/lorin/Desktop/contracttest.py", line 10, in delete_file

----------------------------------------------------------------------
File "/Users/lorin/Desktop/contracttest.py", line 17, in contracttest.delete_file
Failed example:
    delete_file('/tmp/myfile.txt')
Expected:
    Called os.path.exists('/tmp/myfile.txt')
    Called os.remove('/tmp/myfile.txt')
Got:
    Called os.remove('/tmp/myfile.txt')


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.055s
```

Comment: Contract seems good. I'm new to this ,so cannot help.